# H2 margin-top conflicts with its Section tag

Tags: css, html

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geewxk1o/1/)

I've got a section tag containing an `h2` tag with some top margin. I cannot understand why the `margin` applied to the h2 tag is not used to distance it from the `section` tag that contains it, but instead to move the `section` away from the `body` tag.

Comment: Could you show what you have done?

Comment: @Kode.Error404 See the fiddle

Comment: It's called margin collapse. And there are lots of duplicate questions.

Comment: Sorry Orion, I didn't know how was it named

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the following:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins

The parent takes the margin of the first child.

Changing the h2 tag to display:inline-block will change the behaviour to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the issue if you want to have a whitespace around your `h2` is this:

```
h2 {
  margin-top:0px;
  padding-top:10px; --> whatever you want but in padding
}
```

In CSS there is a collapse margin. This means that the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Hence in your original fiddle it becomes the margin from the `body`tag